# Returning to main menu (nested lists, c++)

Tags: c++, loops, menu, nested

I have the following code and am trying to figure out how to have the option to return to the main menu by hitting any key, as long as the quit option isn't chosen. I assume something with this while loop is how it is done, but when I execute the code it terminates after 1 iteration. I'm just learning c++ so I'm not quite sure how to navigate through this problem.

```
//Runs a program with a menu that the user can navigate through different options with via text input

#include <iostream>
#include <cctype> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char userinp;
    cout<<"Here is the menu:" << endl;
    cout<<"Help(H)      addIntegers(A)      subDoubles(D)           Quit(Q)";

    cin >> userinp;
    userinp = tolower(userinp);
    int count = 1;
    while (count == 1)
    {
        if (userinp == 'h')
        {   
            cout <<"This is the help menu. Upon returning to the main menu, input A or a to add 2 intergers." << endl;
            cout <<"Input D or d to subtract 2 doubles. Input Q or q to quit.";
            count = 1;
            return count;
        }

        else if (userinp == 'a')
        {
            int a, b, result;
            cout <<"Enter two integers:";
            cin >> a >> b;
            result = a + b;
           cout << "The sum of " << a << " + " << b << " = " << result;
            count = 1;
        return count;
        }
        else if (userinp == 'd')
        {
            double a, b, result;
            cout <<"Enter two integers:";
            cin >> a >> b;
            result = a - b;
            cout << "The difference of " << a << " - " << b << " = " << result;
            count = 1;
            return count;
       }
       else if (userinp == 'q')
       {
            exit(0);
       }
       else
       {
            cout <<"Please input a valid character to navigate the menu - input the letter h for the help menu";
            cout << "Press any key to continue";
            count = 1;
            return count;
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: All of your code flows to `return`, except one -- which does an `exit`. However, `return` is the same as `exit` when called in `main`. You probably want to skip to the next loop iteration: `continue`. (Edit: given your long list of `if`s, you don't even need that.)

Comment: Is there a way to prompt the user to strike a key before returning to the main menu?

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
else
       {
            cout <<"Please input a valid character to navigate the menu - input the letter h for the help      menu";
            cout << "Press any key to continue";
            count = 1;
            return count;
       }
```

and  instead of while(count == 1) change it to while(true)//which means continously loop until q is pressed

```
also have this part inside while loop i.e
  while(true)
{
    cout<<"Here is the menu:" << endl;
    cout<<"Help(H)      addIntegers(A)      subDoubles(D)           Quit(Q)";

    cin >> userinp;
    userinp = tolower(userinp);
}
```

to have a prompt  for continue:
1.add bool cond =true;(before while(true))
2.change while(true) to while(cond)
3.add this else block  after else if (userinp == 'q')  block

```
else
 {          char ch;
            cout << "Press y to continue";
            cin>>ch;
            if(ch=='y')   
        {
         cond =true;
        }
else
{
cond =false;
exit(0);
}


       }
```

Comment: I want there to be an option to ensure that if one of the 4 commands isn't executed it prompts the user that they need to enter one of the 4 commands without exiting the program.

Comment: I changed the while loop to be while(true) and it's still exiting after 1 iteration :(

Comment: Thank you! This is working. I was wondering though...is there a way to prompt the user to strike a key before returning to the main menu?

Comment: if u want that u add an else block again like this

Comment: @Sean edited again as per your requirement .plz accept answer if it helped you.